# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getRenderingRef' before initialization at stencilSubscription$1

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

I'm using stenciljs to build my project via prerendering. However, the hydration happens below error.

`package.json`

```
"build": "stencil build --prerender --config stencil.config.ts",
```

`output`

```
[ ERROR ]  Hydrate Error
           ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getRenderingRef' before initialization at stencilSubscription$1
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:4996:5) at createStore$2
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:5138:13) at createRouter
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:5148:42) at hydrateAppClosure
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:5529:1) at hydrateFactory
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:34029:3) at render
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:34296:9) at
           C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:34228:62 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at
           Object.hydrateDocument (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\dist\hydrate\index.js:34220:33) at prerenderWorker
           (C:\Users\aleung\Desktop\project\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:9988:46)
```

`stencil.config.ts`

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

export const config: Config = {
    namespace: 'project',
    globalStyle: 'src/global/app.css',
    globalScript: 'src/global/app.ts',
    taskQueue: 'async',
    outputTargets: [
        {
            type: 'www',
            // comment the following line to disable service workers in production
            serviceWorker: null,
            baseUrl: 'https://myapp.local/',
        },
    ],
    plugins: [],
    rollupPlugins: {
        after: [nodePolyfills()],
    },
    devServer: {
        reloadStrategy: 'pageReload',
        openBrowser: false,
    },
};
```

I expect the hydrate can be generated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, your output target needs a `prerenderConfig` property:

```
outputTargets: [
    {
        type: 'www',
        // comment the following line to disable service workers in production
        serviceWorker: null,
        baseUrl: 'https://myapp.local/',
        prerenderConfig: './prerender.config.ts'
    },
],
```

And that file needs to export a `PrerenderConfig` not `Config`:

```
import { PrerenderConfig } from '@stencil/core';
export const config: PrerenderConfig = {
  ...
};
```

See https://stenciljs.com/docs/prerender-config